# Access array inside of object [React] javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Cant seem to get this to work:

just want to show each note item on its own line

```
function EventsTimeline() {
  const timelineEvents = [
    {
      date: 'January',
      note: "Words words words"
    },
    {
      date: 'March',
      note: 'Scaling open maps for Jakarta flooding — and printed maps'
    },
    {
      date: 'August',
      note: 'more stuff ',
    },
    {
      date: 'September',
      note: ["Hurricane Harvey recovery maps", "dfdfdfff" ]
    },
    {
      date: 'October',
      note: 'Resdfsdfd dgdgdg'
    },
    {
      date: 'November',
      note: 'omus omus mos'
    },
    {
      date: 'December',
      note: 'rrrrrrs',
    }
  ];
  let eventPositionCount = -1;
  let eventPositionClass,
    eventDescription = null;
  const eventElements = timelineEvents.map((event, i) => {

      eventPositionCount++;
      eventPositionClass = eventPositionCount % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';

       if (event.note[0].length !== 1 ) {


        for (i = 0; i < event.note.length; i++) { 
            const a = event.note[i]

          eventDescription = <p className="txt-s">{a}</p>;
        }



      } else {
        eventDescription = <p className="txt-s">{event.note}</p>;
      }
```

Ive tried many different ways but nothing works.. what am i doing wrong? Currently I can't even get it to recognize the note or date associated with the array

```
    if (Array.isArray(event.note) == true ){

        const a = event.note

        a.map(function(item) {
         eventDescription = {item}

        })
} else {

eventDescription = <p className="txt-s">{event.note}</p>;

}
```

the expected output is just a list.. 
September

Hurrican Harvey ..etc

dfdfdfff

Comment: Can you specify in the question what output you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The way the code works now, it creates a single `eventDescription` variable, then re-sets that variable to a single element over and over on each loop. Instead, you need that variable to be a *list* of elements, and not just a single one. Here's what you can do:

```
function EventsTimeline() {
  const eventDescriptionElements = timelineEvents.map((event, i) => {
    // here, if the note property isn't already an array, we'll make it one
    // otherwise, we'll keep it as-is
    // this makes it so that we can always use .map even if it's just one array value
    const notes = Array.isArray(event.note) ? event.note : [event.note]

    const noteElements = notes.map((noteText, i) => {
      // key is required in array elements to silence the react warning
      return <p key={i}>{noteText}</p>
    })

    return (
      <p key={i} className="txt-s">
        {noteElements}
      </p>
    )
  })

  return <div>{eventDescriptionElements}</div>
}
```

Also, for the even/odd logic you have there: there's no need to create a separate `eventPositionCount` variable, since the `i` variable inside of the `.map(...)` already does that for you.

```
eventPositionClass = i % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
```

Comment: i dont think im understanding things.. i ran your code and only get an error ..unexpected token

Comment: It looks like I missed a detail in the original question - I've updated my answer to reflect that. Now I wrote it to show what the full component would look like

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like below

```
function eventsTimeLine() {
    timelineEvent.map( event => {
        <div>  
            <p> 
                {Array.isArray(event.note) ?
                    event.note.map( words => (
                        <span> words </span> 
                    :  <span> event.note </span>  
                }
            </p>

        </div>
    });



}
```